# Position Div Relation To Body - Outside Of Parent Div

Tags: jquery, html, popup, onclick, parent-child

I'm having trouble with popup divs. I want to be able to position popups relative to the body so that they are not centred. The problem I have is that they are nested within the navigation div and I can only position them relative to this as it has to be positioned absolutely as I want this to appear in the center of the screen.

So the two issues I have are:

- Can't position Div in relation to body.
- When divs appear they push the navigation items out of place.

Solution:

- Find a way to make the divs ignore it's current parent div and position itself relevant to the body div.

Below you can find my code in a jsFiddle and thank you in advance for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/Uj3R7/5/

### HTML

```
<div id="menu">

    <div id="name"><a href="" title="">name</a></div>

    <ul id="nav">

        <li><a class="pop-up-link" href="#" title="about">about</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
            <div class='about'><a href='#' title="close" class='close'><img src='img/close.png' alt='close' height="20" width="20" /></a>
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a class="pop-up-link" href="#" title="press">press</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
            <div class='press'><a href='#' title="close" class='close'><img src='img/close.png' alt='close' height="20" width="20" /></a>
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a class="pop-up-link" href="#" title="diary">contact</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
            <div class='contact'><a href='#' title="close" class='close'><img src='img/close.png' alt='close' height="20" width="20" /></a>
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a class="pop-up-link" href="#" title="contact">diary</a>
            <div class='diary'><a href='#' title="close" class='close'><img src='img/close.png' alt='close' height="20" width="20" /></a>
                <p>content</p>

            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu {
    position:fixed;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#name {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#nav li{
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
}

.close { 
    float: right; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 99999; 
    margin: 3px 6px 0; 
}

.about { 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 5px; 
    background: #F7E39A; 
    display:none; 
    width:500px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    min-height: 200px; }

.press { 
    position: relative; 
    float: right; 
    top: -200px; 
    right: 500px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    background: #DEA1B7; 
    display:none; 
    width:250px; 
    min-height: 200px; 
}

.contact { 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 5px; 
    background: #6666FA; 
    display:none; 
    width:500px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    min-height: 200px; 
}

.diary { 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    top: 0px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    background: none; 
    border: #291DFA 1px solid; 
    display:none; 
    width:100px; 
    min-height: 200px; 
}​
```

### jQuery

```
$(function() {

    var height = $(document).height();
    var width = $(document).width();
    var spanHeight = $('.popup').height();
    var spanWidth = 500;

    $('.pop-up-link').click(function() { 

        $(this).next() 
        .css({ "top" :  height/2 - spanHeight/2 }) // Centre Pop Up
        .css({ "left" : width/2 - spanWidth/2 })    
        .fadeIn(500);
    });

    $(".close").click(function () {
        $('.pop-up-link').next().fadeOut(500);
    });
});​
```

### Solution

I reworked the code to allow the popups to be children of the body tag so that I could position them relative to the body. I am using SimpleModels and positioning the divs using percentages.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#menu .about').click(function (e) {
        $('#about-content').modal({position: ["20%","65%"]});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: So are the divs suppose to all appear in the same spot? I am not really sure what you are asking here. What do you mean by relative to the body? What is suppose to be the body?

Comment: Also I am wondering why you have these divs inside of your navigation? Is this suppose to be a dropdown?

Comment: Hi @KrisHollenbeck, thanks for your reply. I mean in relation to the <body> tag. I want to make a div with content which will appear when I click on the link. If you look at the image I have attached you can see where I would like them to appear. - - -   

I have them inside the navigation as the jQuery I'm using calls the next div after the link so them need to be inside. I guess this is what I need to change but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address this task, we're going to be focusing on the [CSS attribute "position"](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). However, since we can't see all off the CSS that is present in your example, there may be inheritance issues.

To position multiple child elements with respect from the upper-right corner of the parent, a few things must be made true.

- The parent element has a value for "position" that is not equal to "static".
- Each of the children elements must have a "position" value of "absolute".
- Each of the children elements should have a "top" and "left" value (positive or negative), which describes its offset from standard positioning within the parent element.

Since the <div>s that we are trying to position are moderately deep within the <body>, I am not sure we should take chances with positioning, when changing the CSS of elements between them can drastically move our positioning.

My personal suggestion is to relocate the <div>s that you are looking to position within the <body> up on the DOM so that they are an immediate child of the <body>. Then, with the <body>'s "position" set to probably "relative" (may be unnecessary as it is the root displayed element), we can then position our <div>s with style="position:absolute; top:NN; left:NN;", where NN is some integer value. This would then meet your goal of positioning with respect to the <body>.

P.S. If you ever wanted to position relative to somewhere else on the page (say, the center), simply create a centered 1x1 <div> there with style="position:relative;", and place your positioned elements within that one instead.

I think that you'll find css positioning to be a huge asset in your web design endeavors, especially when combined with styles such as [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vail. Although I thought I had a good understanding of positioning you've opened my eyes to aspects I didn't consider.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is how positioning is used.

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the flow of a layout. They exist as a "layer" in their own universe, stacked using z-index.

Relatively-positioned elements ARE part of the layout - so moving them around can change the flow.

`position:absolute` - this positions an element relative to the first **parent** that has `position:relative` set. If no parent is set, the position will be inherited from the `BODY`. Think of it as setting the origin point - the first relatively-positioned parent becomes the origin point.

If you want to position a general-purpose dialog you generally want it to be either a child of the BODY tag (if you want to position it relative to the browser window), or to have it as a child of the outside wrapper of your layout (to position it to the layout, such as when you have a design that is centered on the screen).

You generally want to avoid using `position:relative` for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus. You answer helped me understand were I was going wrong. I have reworked my jQuery to allow me to place the dialog boxes as children of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/LtsJ4/5/

These are the changes I made

- made the `position` style element `absolute` on all four divs
- changed `document` to `'body'` in your javascript code
- added `"px"` to your css calls.

Comment: Thanks @Kris for your help. I reworked my code to take the dives out of the navigation div in the end.